# ROS2 Humble Installation: Failed to build vision package

Tags: ros-humble, windows, nvidia

I am installing Ros2 humble on windows 11 so that I can make bridge with omniverse

In the installation process  while building vision_msgs pkg I am getting this error,

[image]

The installation guide which I am referring to can be found here-
https://docs.omniverse.nvidia.com/isaacsim/latest/installation/install_ros.html

can anybody tell me where I am going wrong

TIA

Comment: Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)...